# How to optimize a MySQL query to get data from one table which is not present in another table?

Tags: mysql, left-join, query-optimization

I have two MySQL tables named "table1" and "table2", with "table1" containing 1 million rows of data and "table2" containing 0.76 million rows of data. I want to retrieve all the data from "table1" that does not exist in "table2". I tried using a LEFT JOIN in my query, but the query is taking a very long time to execute and has not returned any results after 117965 seconds. I was expecting to get the result much faster.

I'm now looking for suggestions on how to optimize the query or find a more efficient way to get the result. Can anyone help me with this problem?

I tried the following query to get data from table1 that is not present in table2:

```
SELECT t1.part, t2.company 
FROM table1 t1 
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.part = t2.part AND t1.company = t2.company 
WHERE t2.company IS NULL;
```

Comment: use `EXPLAIN` to see where you need an additional index

Comment: @Jens - Unfortunately, `EXPLAIN` usually fails to give any clues about what index is missing.

Answer (score 0):

`table2` needs this composite index:

```
INDEX(part, company)
```

(The order of columns is not important.)

You could also phrase it using `WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM t2 ... )`, but it would probably be the same speed.

I question your use of `SELECT t1.part, t2.company`.  `t2.company` is necessarily `NULL`.  Probably you meant `t1.company`?

And "want to retrieve all the data from "table1"" -- Perhaps you want `SELECT t1.*`